# ag-Grid React - exporting data from grid as excel file (.xls, .xlsx)

Tags: excel, reactjs, export, export-to-excel, ag-grid

I would like to be able to export my grid data as excel files, however as ag-Grid doesn't support this yet I have to come up with my own export function it. The problem I am having is that most of the examples I have seen rely on the fact that the data will be being extracted from an HTML table whereas ag-Grid compiles into `<div>`s so what would be the best way to write a function to export my data as a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file?

Thanks for your time